# source of the chasidic custom not to say tachnun on yahrzeit

Tags: minhag, tefilla, chasidut-hasidism, tachanun, yahrtzeit

I attended today a chasidic minyan and they did not say tachnun because it was the yahrzeit of a certain rebbe.

What is the source of this? Shouldn't this be a sad day?

Comment: The Artscroll Ohel Sarah siddur makes two tangential points: 1. Because it was based on a minhag and never established as an obligation, there are many exemptions (tur o"c 131 and darchei moshe there s"k 5) and that it isn;t said in beit avel during shivah so the connection to "sad" may not be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This custom is brought in various modern Chassidic sefarim. See [Chayei Halevi](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_47229_64.pdf) and מנהג ישראל תורה ח''א סי' קלא 
[R' Yaakov Yosef](http://www.inn.co.il/Articles/Article.aspx/8236) quotes the Minchas Yitzchak who challenges this custom, as surely every day is someone prominent's Yartzheit, and so Tachanun may never be said!

Comment: Well, given that there were over 1200000 prophets, the chances of any day not being a Yartzheit of a big Tzaddik is infinitesimal.